# how to compile angular script code which is created by angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

i has just created one directive which create script file and appended that file to html body element.

But angular code not working in that file. if I write java script code that is working fine.

```
application.directive("dynamicScript",
function(service,$compile,$http,$rootScope){
    return {
        restrict:"E",
         terminal: true,
        scope:{

        },
        link:function(scope,element,attrs){

            //scope.scriptname = attrs.name;
            //service.setData(attrs.name);

            //$http.get('generatescript').then(function(response) {
                var scriptElem = angular.element(document.createElement('script'))
                scriptElem.attr("src", "./js/SAMPLEScript.js")
                scriptElem.attr("type", "text/javascript")
                //element.html('').append( $compile( scriptElem.contents() )( $rootScope ) );
                var ele = angular.element(document.getElementsByTagName("body")).append(scriptElem);
                $compile(scriptElem.contents())(scope);

            //});

        }
    }
});
```

SAMPLEScript.js contains angular script code which is not working. how to load this file working currectly .

Answer (score 0):

You can create directives as shown in Angular jar documentation. It will help to avoid explicit compile and You can directly use compile function also.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Comment: tried but its not working.Rather than creating script code i included script file in response html file, then also angular script code not working. if file contains plain java script code.its working fine.      <br/> Using $compile i compiled the response code then angular directive which i have written inside response html loading perfectly but problem with script code.